# Why is Woodlesford pronounced the way it is?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is Woodlesford pronounced as Woo-dles-ford but not Wood-les-ford? Is there an "L" sound? Wikipedia says, "Widlesford, Wryd(e)lesford(e) and *wrīdels + ford", which confuse me even more.

Comment: Place name pronunciations  are notoriously difficult to guess.  Even native speakers don’t always get it right.

Comment: And folks in Leeds are apt to pronounce it differently from people in Rothwell.

Comment: There are many places where even the inhabitants are split over the pronunciation. There is an ancient but fairly small community in Nottinghamshire called "Southwell" but half the population call it "South Well" and the other half call it "Suthell". Pretty much the same applies to Shrewsbury/Shrowsbry/Salop (that's one place written "Shrewsbury" but referred to differently by different groups of its inhabitants).

Comment: The confusing terms are Medieval forms of the name. Wikipedia actually gives the pronunciation as the second word in the article.  /ˈwʊdəlzfərd/

Comment: @AndrewLeach : There is a reliable person told me *how* to pronounce it, so I don't have a problem with that. What I don't understand is *why*. Maybe knowing the etymology of the name (or Medieval or Old English in general) could help, but I ain't any good in any language.

Comment: Think about words like noodles. You wouldn't pronounce that like nood-less.

Comment: @siride : That's really useful. I think I understand it now. What a simple and straightforward answer! I've been thinking -ford is Anglo-Saxon. Apparently, I have made it unnecessarily complicated, which is decidedly out of my depth.

Comment: Ford most certainly is Anglo-Saxon. It's just another component of the word.

Answer (score 1):

*[The following was written when the question was titled, erroneously as it turned out, "How to pronounce Woodlesford?"]*

It is /ˈwʊdᵊlzfəd/ according to the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* (3rd ed., 2008), *The Routledge Dictionary of Pronunciation for Current English* (2017), and the *BBC Pronouncing Dictionary of British Names* (2nd ed., 1983). /ᵊl/ is either a syllabic consonant ([l̩]) or a schwa + lateral ([əl]) depending on your accent, and the last syllable would be /fərd/ if you're a rhotic speaker.